# How to run Ubuntu alongside other OS on laptop

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

How do you partition HD on Lenovo thinkpad to run Ubuntu along w/other enterprise software.  Do I need a VMware or some other kind of Hypervisor to spin it up? Is there something free that I might be able to use?

Comment: There is documentation on how to do this on Ubuntu's official website: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Use KVM - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to run one OS, shut it down, and boot the other; or run one OS while the other is running (so you've got simultaneous access to both OSes and their applications)? To date, answerers have assumed one or the other interpretation, but the possibilities are completely different for each interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get an .iso from Ubuntu, then write in onto a flash drive (not copy it). After you boot from the flash drive, go to the option to install Ubuntu. Once you do that, it will give you the option to install alongside your current OS.